# Error wanting to get green RGB channel from an image

Tags: c++, opencv, rgb

I have been looking for ways to use OpenCV to separate RGB layers and extract only the green layer of an image, but I have obtained these errors when I want to run the executable that was generated from the code, the code I have made is this:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp> 
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat img, g, fin_img;
img = imread("img.png",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
vector<Mat> channels(3);

g = Mat::zeros(Size(img.rows, img.cols), img.type());

channels.push_back(g);
channels.push_back(g);
channels.push_back(img);

merge(channels, fin_img);
imshow("img", fin_img);
waitKey(0);
return 0;
```

The error is this:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (mv[i].size == mv[0].size && mv[i].depth() == depth) in merge, file /opt/opencv/modules/core/src/convert.cpp, line 336
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>     what():  /opt/opencv/modules/core/src/convert.cpp:336: error: (-215) mv[i].size == mv[0].size && mv[i].depth() == depth in function merge

Comment: `rows = src.rows;` Is it just me or `src` is missing?

Comment: I corrected the code, an apology, however this code does compile, but when it comes to wanting to execute it, it shows the error that I put

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the [split](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga0547c7fed86152d7e9d0096029c8518a) function

```
Mat a = imread(path);
Mat channels[3];
split(a, channels);
imshow("Green", channels[1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are first creating a vector with 3 empty matrices, and then you're pushing back 3 other matrices, resulting in a vector of 6 matrices with different sizes.

Simply create an empty vector to begin with:

```
vector<Mat> channels;
g = Mat::zeros(Size(img.rows, img.cols), img.type());
channels.push_back(g);
channels.push_back(g);     
channels.push_back(img);
```

However what you're doing is not extracting the green channel. To do this you need to `split` and `merge`, or you can use [cv::extractChannel](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gacc6158574aa1f0281878c955bcf35642):

```
cv::Mat green;
cv::extractChannel(image, green, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

(guessing as the hunk you gave does not compile)

```
Mat black = Mat::zeros(rows, cols, src.type());
```

seem wrong, if the input image has 3 channels, you want a single channel here, thus the `src.type()` cannot be used here.

Comment: I corrected the code, an apology, however this code does compile, but when it comes to wanting to execute it, it shows the error that I put